# ASP.NET Core - AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I have IdentityDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
            entity.HasIndex(u => u.UserName).IsUnique();
        });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(r => r.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique();
        });
}
```

IdentityModel:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
 {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
 }

 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
 {
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
 }

 public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
 {
    public override long UserId { get; set; }
    public override long RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
 }
}
```

LoginRequestDto:

```
public class LoginRequestDto
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password is required!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

AuthMapper:

```
public class AuthMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AuthMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();

}
```

Services:

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request);
}

public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public AuthService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IMapper mapper,
        MyDbContext context

    )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<object>();

        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
        {
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };
            foreach (var userRole in roles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }
            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            response.Result = new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),
                expires = token.ValidTo
            };
            response.StatusCode = 200;
            user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto() { ErrorCode = 500, Message = ex.Message };
            }
            return response;
        }

        response.StatusCode = 400;
        response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto { ErrorCode = 400, Message = "Invalid Username or Password!" };

        return response;
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

> Mapping types:
> Object -> UserDto
> System.Object -> DDM.API.Core.DTOs.v1.Authentication.UserDto
> at lambda_method198(Closure , Object , UserDto , ResolutionContext )
> at DDM.API.Core.Services.v1.Concrete.AuthService.LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request) in C:\Users\MyApp\Core\Services\v1\Concrete\AuthService.cs:line 78

This is line 78:

> response.Result = new

startup.cs:

```
  // Auto mapper
  services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

  // Dependency Injection
  services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

controller:

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GenericResponseDto<object>>> Login(LoginRequestDto loginRequest)
    {
        var response = await _authService.LoginUser(loginRequest);
        Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode ?? StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        return new JsonResult(response);
    }
```

What do I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What does your mapper registration as a service look like? Can you add code please?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik - See AuthMapper:  and startup.cs in my code. Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that the type of `user` is `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: @MattU - Yes, it is. See it in MyDbContext

Comment: It looks like you have multiple projects. can your try services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup), typeofof(AuthService));
Also, try moving the assignment out of the object creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your mapping `Profile` is not taken into account, the error message supports this, the error message says Automapper uses mapping of Object to UserDto, instead of ApplicationUser to UserDto.

Try configure the mapper in an alternate way

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddMaps(myAssembly);
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Another option, try mapping manually

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
});
```

Comment: Basically I have three (3) projects: 1. DDM.API.Infrasteucture (It contains the DB Migration and entities. It is referenced by the DDM.API.Core). 2. DDM.API.Core (It consist the DTOs and Services. This is where the mapping is done. It is referenced by DDM.API.Web). 3. DDM.API.Web ( It consist of startup.cs)

Comment: [The documentation for injection](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) states you define the configuration using profiles. And then you let AutoMapper know in what assemblies are those profiles defined by calling the `AddAutoMapper` method. You need to provide the profile type as a parameter: `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AuthMapperProfile));`.

Comment: @mike as Martin pointed out, when you `AddAutoMapper` you need to tell it where any and all `Profile`s live. If `AuthMapperProfile` lives in a separate assembly from `Startup` then that's a problem.